# what to substitute for TThread

Tags: visual-c++, c++builder, tthread

I have source code for USB communication ("USBThread class") written in Borland C++ and uses Visual Component Library("vcl.h"). 
Now my task is to port that to Visual C++, because we did not buy Borland C++.

But this "USBThread class" has inheritance from a base class in "vcl.h", called "TThread".

May I ask , in Visual C++, What kind of base class I can use to substitute "TThread' as new inheritance source?

The original code uses "WaitFor" and "Terminate" methods coming TThread,
I do not know how to implement these two menthods with Visual C++.

Thanks!

Comment: That depends. What do you need this replacement class to do?

Comment: I want to implement "WaitFor" and "Terminate" methods in Visual C++, these two methods inherits from TThread in Borland C++.

Comment: I suppose you don't have the source code for `TThread`, do you? I don't think there's a threading convenience class in Visual C++, so you'll just have to use the Win32 API threading functions directly.

Comment: No, I do not have source code for TThread.

Comment: if you are unable to port it to VC style source you can still use Borland. for example BDS2006 Turbo C++ has free licence for 100 years even for commercial use if you have just single language per machine. It is discontinued but I am sure that you will find it on some p2p network. Also borland 5.5 compiler (which is the same as bds2006 Turbo C++) is for free completely (I think) but it has no IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be a difficult exerice imo but it looks like [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread) using `join` for `WaitFor` and `interrupt` for `Terminate` would get you started.

I am basing this on review of the [docs for VCL found here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread).  I say this is likely to be difficult because VCL may have behaviour that is undocumented or otherwise unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could translate the VCL's `TThread` class into C++, it would not work very well because it relies on some Delphi semantics that simply do not translate to C++ at all (in particular the `TObject::AfterConstruction()` method).  You are best off simply re-writing USBThread to use Win32 thread functions directly, namely `CreateThread()` and  `WaitForSingleObject()`.  For `Terminate()`, you simply set a `bool` flag somewhere that your thread procedure can look at periodically and stop its work when set to true.